# Ruby: changing type of only part of an array

Tags: ruby

I have a whole bunch of arrays, each with integers as strings in slots 1 and 3 through 9, but in each array slot 2 has a time in it (as a string), in minutes:seconds. A sample array would look like this:

["1", "11:49", "345", "26", "123456", "23", "1", "0", "65"]

What I want to do is convert everything except the time into integers, and convert the time into an integer number of seconds. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
["1", "11:49", "345", "26", "123456", "23", "1", "0", "65"]
.map.with_index do |e, i|
  if i == 1
    m, s = e.scan(/\d+/)
    m.to_i.*(60) + s.to_i
  else
    e.to_i
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Only thing I don't quite understand (forgive me, I'm new to ruby) is how I make an output array from this...

Comment: Wondering what was going on until I realized I made a typo and wrote it in wrong. Sorry about that, everything working now.

Answer (score 1):

A slower but *possibly* more readable version sets the second element of a clone of your original array, then maps the `to_i` method

```
>> original = ["1", "11:49", "345", "26", "123456", "23", "1", "0", "65"]

>> a = original.clone
=> ["1", "11:49", "345", "26", "123456", "23", "1", "0", "65"]
>>  m, s = a[1].split(":")
=> ["11", "49"]
>>  a[1] = m.to_i * 60 + s.to_i
=> 709
>> a.map(&:to_i)
=> [1, 709, 345, 26, 123456, 23, 1, 0, 65]
```

In a function:

```
def f(array)
  a = array.clone
  m, s = a[1].split(":")
  a[1] = m.to_i * 60 + s.to_i
  a.map(&:to_i)
end
```

Comment: Ray, I like your approach of avoiding unnecessary `if`s within the loop. You could eliminate the need to clone with: `def f(array); m, s = a[1].split(":").map(&:to_i); a = array.map(&:to_i); a[1] = m * 60 + s; a; end`. Note `"11:30".to_i => 11`; i.e., it does not raise an exception.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
time_to_seconds = -> x {m,s=x.split(':').map(&:to_i);m*60+s}

my_array.map do |num|
  num[':'] ? time_to_seconds[num] : num.to_i
end
```

Comment: But why do the extra work, considering that we know the location of the sole exceptional item (and we probably should be checking that)?